# Fetch nearby GEO results using GEOFirestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am using GeoFirestore to write a cloud function on cloud Firestore to query nearby locations basing on the center and the radius.

The init code looks like this

```
    const firebase = require('firebase');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const GeoFirestore = require("geofirestore").GeoFirestore;
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    const db = admin.firestore();
```

The JS code to query is

```
const object = db.collection('UserObject');
var geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(object);
const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
    center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(17.500362, 78.587374),
    radius: 1
});
geoQuery.on('ready', () => {
    var locations = geoQuery._locationsTracked;
    var keys = [];
    locations.forEach(function (locationMap, key) {
        if (typeof locationMap !== 'undefined' && locationMap.isInQuery) {
            keys.push(locationMap);
        }
    });
    response.status(200).json(keys);
  });
```

I am new to the GeoFirestore library. My question is, is this a proper implementation to get the nearby locations or is there a different way to query the nearby locations using this library ?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of needs a massive reworking, but the solution will be simpler (code explained in comments):

```
const object = db.collection('UserObject');
const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(object);
const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
  center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(17.500362, 78.587374),
  radius: 1
});

// Where we will store the results
const results = [];

// As documents come in, push them into our results
geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, document) => results.push(document));

// After the query is initially complete we then send the results to the client
geoQuery.on('ready', () => response.status(200).json(results));
```